How to turn off the (auto)terminal output while rendering blender file in headless mode?
I'm using blender rendering with my own python script in headless mode. Some how when blender rendering in headless mode, it automatically print the rendering process it went through. The terminal print out a lot of information about blender rendering.like:
"Fra:0 Mem:27.60M (Peak 52.27M) | Time:00:00.19 | Mem:8.04M, Peak:8.04M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Scene
Fra:0 Mem:27.60M (Peak 52.27M) | Time:00:00.19 | Mem:8.04M, Peak:8.04M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Shaders
Fra:0 Mem:27.68M (Peak 52.27M) | Time:00:00.19 | Mem:8.05M, Peak:8.05M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Procedurals
Fra:0 Mem:27.68M (Peak 52.27M) | Time:00:00.19 | Mem:8.05M, Peak:8.05M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Background
Fra:0 Mem:27.68M (Peak 52.27M) | Time:00:00.19 | Mem:8.05M, Peak:8.05M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Camera
Fra:0 Mem:27.68M (Peak 52.27M) | Time:00:00.19 | Mem:8.05M, Peak:8.05M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Meshes Flags
Fra:0 Mem:27.68M (Peak 52.27M) | Time:00:00.19 | Mem:8.05M, Peak:8.05M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Objects
Fra:0 Mem:27.68M (Peak 52.27M) | Time:00:00.19 | Mem:8.05M, Peak:8.05M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Objects | Copying Transformations to device"


There are too many of them that i can not see my own python script print output,it is so difficult to understand where i was in the whole process. It became a big problem when i need to test and debug the program. How do i turn it off? without turning off my own script print output?
I'm using command
./blender -b  D:\gitproject\smi_data_generation\release\tsr_1.0_win\tsrscene_V6.blend --python D:\gitproject\smi_data_generation\release\tsr_1.0_win\pipeline.py
for headless rendering.
